# Kendo UI PopUp not passing values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

The grid and popup work fine except the values I enter in create mode do not get passed back to my controller. Looking at the JS Console shows no errors. Monitoring the create process in Fiddler also shows no values being passed, although my form elements do show.

While debugging, the model in my controller is empty.

Here's the grid definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyApp.Domain.Entities.TaktInterruptionViewModel>()
.Name("Interruptions")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(i => i.TaktInterruptionId).Hidden().IncludeInMenu(false);
        columns.Bound(i => i.DateCreated).Title("Date").Width(75).Format("{0:d}");
        columns.Bound(i => i.ActionCount).Title("Actions").Width(50).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(i => i.MeetingType).Title("Meeting   Type").Width(100).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(i => i.AreaName);
        columns.Bound(i => i.TypeName);
        columns.Bound(i => i.Responsible);
        columns.Bound(i => i.Description).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(i => i.Interruption).Width(75).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(i => i.TaktMissed).Title("Missed").Width(75);
    })
.ClientDetailTemplateId("ActionsTemplate")
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Interruption"))
.Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Create").Window(w => w.Title("Interruption").Name("addInterruption").Modal(true)))
.DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.TaktInterruptionId))
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .PageSize(5)
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Home"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetInterruptions", "Home")))
.Groupable()
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.ColumnMenu()
.Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.Events(events => events.Change("displayChart"))
)
```

My create editor template is as follows:

```
@model MyApp.Domain.Entities.TaktInterruptionViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="span-14" style="padding: 10px;">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <hr class="space" />
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("DateCreated").Value(DateTime.Today))
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated, null, new { style =    "color:red;" })
    </div>
    <hr class="space" />
    <div class="span-7">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaId)<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaId)
            .Name("AreaId")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
            .OptionLabel("Select Area...")
            .DataTextField("AreaName")
            .DataValueField("AreaId")
            .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetAreas", "Area");
                        });
                })
         )
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaId)
    </div>
    <div class="span-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaktInterruptionTypeId)<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.TaktInterruptionTypeId)
            .Name("TaktInterruptionTypeId")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 200px" })
            .OptionLabel("Select Type...")
            .DataTextField("TypeName")
            .DataValueField("TaktInterruptionTypeId")
            .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetTypes", "Area").Data("filterTypes");
                        }).ServerFiltering(true);
                })
                .Enable(false)
                .AutoBind(false)
                .CascadeFrom("AreaId")
         )
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaktInterruptionTypeId, null, new { style = "color:red;" })
    </div>
    <hr class="space" />
    <div class="span-11">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "multi-line" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, null, new { style = "color:red;" })
    </div>
    <hr class="space" />
    <div class="span-5">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interruption)<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox().Name("Interruption").Format("#.0").Value(0))
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interruption)
    </div>
    <div class="span-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaktMissed)<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox().Name("TaktMissed").Format("#.0").Value(0))
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaktMissed)
    </div>
    <hr class="space" />
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Responsible)<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Responsible, new { @class = "k-input k-textbox" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Responsible, null, new { style = "color:red;" })
    </div>
    <hr class="space" />
    <hr class="space" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function filterTypes() {
        return {
        AreaID: $("#AreaId").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

And my controller create method is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyApp.Domain.Entities.TaktInterruptionViewModel taktInterruption)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // code removed for brevity
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["message"] = "There was a problem saving the takt interruption.\n" + ex.Message;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

If I remove my editor template from the equation and allow kendo to do the popup, the information is passed to my controller; however, I want to control the layout of the popup and I also have cascading drop-downs (that work), thus the editor template.

My question is why aren't my values that I enter in the popup being passed to my controller?

Comment: Anybody? Surely, somebody has done this before. I'm really stuck and need help here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug or limitation to using the custom editor template, however, to get around this I subscribed to the JavaScript Edit event and set the drop down list value.

```
function reassignVacancy_Editing(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var reassignUserList = $("#reassignUserList").data("kendoComboBox");

    reassignUserList.value(e.model.UserId);
}
```

I also needed to handle the save event and update the model:

```
function reassignVacancy_Saving(e)
    {
        // Update the ViewModel

        var reassignUserList = $("#reassignUserList").data("kendoComboBox");

        e.model.UserName = reassignUserList.dataItem().FullName;  // For the benefit of the grid
        e.model.UserId = reassignUserList.dataItem().Id;            
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

kendo pop up edit, take values from grid not template, when you enter a value, template modifies the cell of new row. 
For example;

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("DateCreated").Value(DateTime.Today))
 @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox().Name("TaktMissed").Format("#.0").Value(0))
```

These have a default value. If you don't change their values, they won't be posted to controller. For posting you have to write values to grid cell.

```
    var firstItem = $('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[0];
    firstItem.set('ColumnName', DefaultValue);
```

Comment: I was stuck on this for 2 hours. Thanks!